# How to split a string log file which starts by date in square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split a log string into separate logs into an array, the string looks like this:
`'[2016-12-01 11:24:28.622] [INFO] Scraper - Processing year 2016 [2016-12-01 11:24:28.622] [INFO] Scraper - Successfully proccessed  ....'`
I tried using `.split()` function, but managed only to split by `[INFO]`.
Is there a regexp to use to split by date in square brackets ?
I'm new to regexp, would much appreciate any suggestions, thanks.
The desired outcome looks like this

```
['[2016-12-01 11:24:28.622] [INFO] Scraper - Processing year 2016', '[2016-12-01 11:24:28.622] [INFO] Scraper - Successfully proccessed  ....']
```

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried. read more: [mcve]

Comment: aren't those entries 1 per line? Just split by linebreak

Comment: Fallenhero, thanks for suggestion, I've tried that. Lines seem to break if the string is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
yourString.split(/(?=\[\d)/)
```

This splits your string at every `[<number>` (`\[\d`) without consuming those themselves - look-ahead (`(?=...)`)

Comment: Fallenhero, thank you so much! This worked.